# C++ UDP server breakdown

Tags: c++, udp

C++ when used in networking is completely cryptic to me. Would anyone mind helping me break down the errors in this code? It was given to my class as an example of how not to make a UDP server.

I already notice a few issues like how the buffers are a fixed 256 bytes long, but for the most part I don't understand it. I'm more of a PHP/Java/JavaScript programmer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, portno, clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc <= 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"Error, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }

     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("Error opening socket");

     bzero((char *) &cli_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[2]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(cli_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

     while(100)
     {
        bzero(buffer,256);
        n = recvfrom(sockfd,buffer, 0, 255,
                 (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,&clilen);

        printf("A client from %s port %d connected\n", inet_aton(cli_addr.sin_addr), htons(cli_addr.sin_port));

        if (n < 0) error("Error reading from socket");
        printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
        n = sendto(sockfd,"I got your message",18,0,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(cli_addr));
        if (n < 0) error("Error writing to socket");
     }

     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at [Unix Network Programming](http://www.unpbook.com/). Explaining how to make a UDP server is a pretty tall order for a StackOverflow question.

Comment: This is a Q&A site on specific issues/facts, not a "plz help" tutorial environment. Sorry. If this is homework, you should ask your teacher/tutor for help; that's what they're there for.

Comment: I'm specifically looking for errors, so I figured that was specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it? Use nc/aka netcat to try sending UDP packets too it.

Oh and here is another clue from socket()'s man page

```
SOCK_STREAM     Provides sequenced, reliable, two-way, connection-based byte streams.   An  out-of-band data transmission mechanism may be supported
SOCK_DGRAM      Supports datagrams (connectionless, unreliable messages of a fixed maximum length).
```

An you are right about the buffer size although it should not overflow - I would use 2^16 aka 65536 as this is the largest UDP packet supported in IPv4

Answer (score 1):

`socket` function creates the socket handle for your server socket. `bind` function binds your socket handle to the specified IP address (`INADDR_ANY`) and port (via `serv_addr`). In your while loop, it receives data from a client via `recvfrom` function and prints the data out. `sendto` function sends the reply back to the client. `close` function closes your socket handle.